# Previous, Current & Next Functionality for 2 dimentional array in typescript (Angular)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array of json object with array like this:

```
sampleArr = [{"c":0,"p":[0,1]},{"c":1,"p":[0,1,2,3]},{"c":2,"p":[0]}]
```

I want to implement a functionality for buttons:

```
<div (click)="previousItem()">Chapter 0 & Product 0</div>
<div>Active Chapter 0 & Product 1</div>
<div (click)="nextItem()">Chapter 1 & Product 0</div>
```

On clicking next function the result for active p & c should be:

```
1st click : c - 1; p - 0
2nd click : c - 1; p - 1
3rd click : c - 1; p - 2
4th click : c - 1; p - 3
5th click : c - 2; p - 0
6th click : c - 0; p - 0
7th click : c - 0; p - 1
..and so on
```

On clicking previous function the result for active p & c should should reverse the loop.

The active element will always be the current element.
If anyone can please help in writing this peice of code?
I am using Angular 10.

Comment: tip: use two variables `indexC` and `indexP`, you are in the element `this.sampleArr[this.indexC].p[this.indexP]`. Just only consider when you're at last or at first of a P. NOTE: use `this.sampleArr[this.indexC].p.length` to know the length of the sub array "p" actual

Comment: Can you please help me out on fiddle? I am bit confused when there are uneven elements to be taken care of.

Comment: nop, sorry, I think you need try "something" not only ask (Appologies if this is not the answer you expect)

Comment: Oh, no problem! It's just going complex when tried with lengthy json object with lots of variables and data. Anyways, appreciate your help!

Comment: Does the value of the `c` property always correspond to the index in the containing array?  I mean, do you need to do `sampleArr.find(o => o.c===i)` or can you just do `sampleArr[i]`?

Comment: I think a concrete [mcve] where you show exactly what you expect the output of `previousItem()` and `nextItem()` to be... if it's supposed to affect some variables or state, your example should define those variables or state.  I can come up with some index-fiddling code like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlpDON), but I don't know if you would consider that an answer because it doesn't have anything to do with angular or buttons or clicking.